# Ad not loading on android,react-native-firebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using `react-native-firebase`.

Native module is successfully linked but when I try to show ad rewarded, the video not loaded.

What can be the reason?

Comment: can you give some brief about your code ?

Comment: @AndroidTeam this is the code of ad: https://gist.github.com/EHakobyan/467d8150ac96c5e011147b1906e01777#file-firebasead